# What is this brown, 4-pointed seed pod?

Tags: identification, seeds

Please help me to identify the seed. 
I attach the image of the pod.
It was found near the ocean's beach in Boston. 
I would appreciate any input.

[image]
[image]

Comment: That thing is pretty cool looking - had you not identified it as a plant or pod, I would almost think it could be a very bitey fossilized specimen!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These are seeds from Trapa natans or "[Water Caltrop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_caltrop)" or "European Water Chestnut". You're good at finding [invasive plant seeds](http://www.invadingspecies.com/invaders/plants-aquatic/european-water-chestnut/)! :)

[image]

Comment: Oooh, sorry Brenn, you must have posted while I was faffing about selecting a good image online...

Comment: No worries! You get my vote! ;)

Comment: You got mine, but I'm probably gonna delete my answer...

Comment: Wow, Brenn, thank you! You seem to know 'em all:))

Comment: This Brenn was RAISED in a family of gardeners and his home was a greenhouse (grins) and nursery!!

Comment: Lol. Too funny @stormy. You forgot to mention that I sleep in a flower bed.

Comment: Like Br'er Rabbit?  Major grins!